# Урезание файла

Tags: php

Есть тектовый файл с содержимым.
Я его урезаю

```
$rf=fopen('1.txt','w+');
ftruncate($rf,100)
```

Почему теперь при открытии файла у меня вместо букв такие то черные квадратики и при открытии файла выводится сообщения "открыть бинарный файл?" 
Возвращаемые значения-Возвращает TRUE .

```
  echo ftruncate ( $rf, 2000 );//1
```

Comment: а не был ли часом в файле Unicode-текст?

Comment: что-то мне подсказывает,что Вы правы.Наверно текстовый файл был создан не в той кодировке.У файле были только буквы и переносы строк.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если текст был в формате Unicode, то обрезав его в "случайном" месте, вы испортили его. Дело в том, что символы Unicode имеют длину в байтах более 1 (в некоторых вариантах всегда 2, в некоторых переменное число), а также в начале файла возможен BOM (насколько мне известно, он обычно имеет длину 3 -- нечётную). Поэтому велика вероятность, что ваш разрез пришёлся на середину символа. Столкнувшись с этим, редактор не воспримет файл как Unicode, а будет пытаться интерпретировать его как текст.

Простое решение таково: откройте файл как *текстовый*, прочитайте первые *x* символов, и запишите с сохранением формата в другой файл. Должно работать.

Comment: спасибо огромное.

Comment: @koza4ok: пожалуйста!